# Riemann Mapping Theorem, Two General Domains

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry, analytic-functions

Exercise states:

Let $D_1, D_2$ be two simply-connected open sets, both not equal to $\mathbb{C}$. Prove that for every $z_0 \in D_1, w_0 \in D_2$ there exists a single biholomorphic function $f : D_1 \to D_2$ such that $$f(z_0)=w_0,\ \ \ \ \ \    \arg(f'(z_0))=\frac{\pi}{2}$$

I managed to prove existence: by the Riemann mapping theorem, there exists a mapping $g_1: D_1 \to \Delta$, $\Delta$ is the open unit circle, such that $$g_1(z_0)=0,\ \ \ \ \ \    \arg(g_1'(z_0))=\frac{\pi}{2}$$ and also there exists a function $g_2 : D_2 \to \Delta$, that satisfies $$g_2(w_0)=0,\ \ \ \ \ \    \arg(g_2'(w_0))=0$$

If we define $f := g_2^{-1} \circ g_1$, then $f(z_0)=w_0$ and
 $\arg(f'(z_0))=\frac{\pi}{2}$. But I didn't find a way to prove uniqueness. What's the way to prove it?

Comment: Do you know the equality case of the Schwarz lemma? It says: if $f$ maps the unit disk to itself, $f(0)=0$, and $f'(0)=1$, then $f$ is the identity. Apply this to a suitable composition of maps.

Comment: @if.... thanks you, that's called a good hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $h_1,h_2 \colon D_1 \to D_2$ satisfying the required conditions. Take $g_2$ from the question.

Define $S = g_2 \circ h_1 \circ h_2^{-1} \circ g_2^{-1} \colon \Delta \to \Delta$.

Then $S(0)=0$, and

$S'(0)=(g_2 \circ h_1 \circ h_2^{-1} \circ g_2^{-1})'(0) =$

$(g_2 \circ h_1 \circ h_2^{-1})'(g_2^{-1}(0)) \cdot (g_2^{-1})'(0) = (g_2 \circ h_1 \circ h_2^{-1})'(w_0) \cdot (g_2^{-1})'(0) =$

$(g_2 \circ h_1)'(h_2^{-1}(w_0)) \cdot (h_2^{-1})'(w_0) \cdot (g_2^{-1})'(0) = (g_2 \circ h_1)'(z_0) \cdot (h_2^{-1})'(w_0) \cdot (g_2^{-1})'(0) =$

$g_2'(h_1(z_0))) \cdot h_1'(z_0) \cdot (h_2^{-1})'(w_0) \cdot (g_2^{-1})'(0) = g_2'(w_0)) \cdot h_1'(z_0) \cdot (h_2^{-1})'(w_0) \cdot (g_2^{-1})'(0) = 1$

By the Schwarz lemma, it follows that $S = Id$, therefore $h_1=h_2$.

QED